# What have I missed ?? fatal error unexpected nil found while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet var txtusername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtpassword: UITextField!

@IBAction func SigninTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
   var username:NSString = txtusername.text
    var password:NSString = txtpassword.text
  if (self.txtusername.text.isEmpty)
    {

        (UIAlertView(title: "Fields cant be empty", message: "Please Enter email id and password",
            delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show())
        return
    }
    else if (range==nil)
    {
        (UIAlertView(title: "Invalid Email Id", message: "Please enter correct email id", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show())
        return
    }
    else if (txtpassword.text == ""  )
    {

        var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertView.title = "Failed!"
        alertView.message = "Please enter Password"
        alertView.delegate = self
        alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertView.show()
        return
    }
    else
    {
        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://192.168.0.31:8097/api/user/GetValidateUser" + "/" + username + "/" + txtpassword.text)!

        var err:NSError?
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept");
        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)


        if ( urlData != nil )
        {
            let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);
            //var   message :String = "Valid user"
            if (res.statusCode == 200)
            {
                if(responseData != "\"Valid user\"")
                {
                    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alertView.title = "Failed"
                    alertView.message = responseData
                    alertView.delegate = self
                    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    alertView.show()
                    return;
                }
                //Get the address book reference
                //GabbersController().GetAddressBook()

                //  var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                //   alertView.title = "Sign in Message"
                //  alertView.message = responseData
                //  alertView.delegate = self
                //  alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                //  alertView.show()
            }

            else {
                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertView.title = "Failed"
                alertView.message = responseData;
                if let error = reponseError {
                    alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
                }
                alertView.delegate = self
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertView.show()
            }


        }

        else {
            var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Failed"
            alertView.message = "Connection failure";
            if let error = reponseError {
                alertView.message = (error.localizedDescription)
            }
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()


        }
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Goto__Gabbers" sender:self;

    }


}
```

For the above code i got that sudden error, for that I thought I may missed reference outlet deleted the existing one and created again in my story board when I run the application same error throwing not getting what actually I missed here. it is executed well at first time but further it is not,throwing fatal unexpected nil error can anybody tell what actually I missed here.

This is the exact error which I am getting:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

posted my full code

Comment: By the way you can use `var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://192.168.0.31:8097/api/user/GetValidateUser/\(txtusername.text)/\(txtpassword.text)")!`

Answer (score 3):

As per Swift1.2 you can do as below.

```
@IBOutlet var txtusername: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtpassword: UITextField!

@IBAction func SigninTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
   if let userName = txtusername.text as? String, let password = txtpassword.text as? String {

    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://192.168.0.31:8097/api/user/GetValidateUser" + "/" + userName + "/" + password)!
    var err:NSError?
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, unfortunately based on OP's premise, the `if` will fail because either `txtusername.text` or `txtpassword.text` will be nil, or else the code should run perfectly. Upvoted.

Comment: i can't get @Schemetrical B'coz textfield's text property returns String so Y we have to define by as String ?? can you explain me.

Comment: not getting solution guys consuming more time help me out i have lot of things to do yet so...

Comment: @NaveenKumar Check if `txtpassword.text` is nil.

Comment: These two lines may crash.   var username:NSString = txtusername.text
    and var password:NSString = txtpassword.text. Coz these two variables are not optional as per declaration, but you are assigning value of optional. Similarly make sure all other place if optional are there make sure you take care of that.

Comment: seriously it is eating my head dude first time it is executed but later on same error even i check if(txt password.text != nil && txtusername.text != nil)

Answer (score 0):

`txtusername.text` and `txtpassword.text` could be `nil` at this point.

You must check if both of these values are not nil, then you can do `var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://192.168.0.31:8097/api/user/GetValidateUser/\(txtusername.text)/\(txtpassword.text)")!`

Comment: actually i checking not null condition then allowing but in question i didn't mention those things

Comment: Are you very sure? It can only happen when either of them are nil.

Comment: and even i tried by assigning variable the n pass those variable to the url no use same error

Comment: Of course assigning them to a variable won't help. I suggest you post the full code detailing you checking for the values and if they are not nil.